# Bootstrap - div in li

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a menu with sub-menus. After moving to the top menu, display sub menu the whole width of the page. It works, but I've problems with mobile menu. I am using bootstrap, but I can't click on links. Code select link is below div. I have to that menu. Have you any ideas, what's wrong ?

```
<ul>
 <li>Head link</li>
 <div id="submenu"><li></li></div>

 <li>Head link</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you understand you need to add a minimal code in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, having such a reputation, I shouldn't answer these kind of questions. I am sorry for that. But in the sense of helping the OP genuinely, I am answering this question. Please do read the How to ask a question in StackOverflow.

A lot of mistakes in your code:

1. You cannot have `<div>` directly inside `<ul>`.
2. You cannot have `<li>` directly inside `<div>`.
3. The `submenu` should be a `class` and not an `id`.
4. All the contents of `<li>` should be wrapped inside `<a>` tag.
5. If you are using the Bootstrap's navigation, you need to use `data-toggle` attributes.

**Corrected Code:**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Head link</a>
    <div id="submenu">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Head link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**With `data-toggle` Attributes:**

```
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-trigger" data-toggle="dropdown">Head link</a>
    <div id="submenu" class="dropdown-menu">
      <ul>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Head link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ok, but  class dropdown has the same width as its parent. In desktop resolution dropdown is to be the full width but mobile it is dropdown. I don't know how connect this.